# How to use htaccess to change a folder name and remove a string from the end of a URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**My Goal**

I'm trying to use htaccess to change URLs like this...

`https://example.com/OLDNAME/item/a-long-file-name-separated-by-hyphens-2`

`https://example.com/OLDNAME/item/a-long-file-name-separated-by-hyphens`

Into URLs like this

`https://example.com/NEWNAME/item/a-long-file-name-separated-by-hyphens`

**The Steps**

1. Replace `OLDNAME` in the URL with `NEWNAME`. This rule should execute anytime 'OLDNAME' is found in the URL.
2. When a URL contains 'OLDNAME', it sometimes has the string '-2' at the end of the URL. If this '-2' string is found, it needs to be removed too.

**What I've tried**

I have the redirect from `OLDNAME` to `NEWNAME` working using this rule...

```
RewriteRule ^OLDNAME/(.*)$ /NEWNAME/$1 [NC]
```

I've read many posts and lots of pages from mod_rewrite documentation, but I haven't made much progress trying to remove the `-2` yet.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```bash
RewriteRule ^OLDNAME/(.+?)(?:-2)?/?$ /NEWNAME/$1 [L,NC,R=302,NE]
```

I assume you want to redirect to new URL hence added `R` flag.

Note pattern in `RewriteRule` that ends with `-2` is outside the capture group. When we use `$1` in target it will be without last `-2`.

**Test Output:**

```bash
curl -I 'localhost/OLDNAME/item/a-long-file-name-separated-by-hyphens'
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 03 Mar 2023 20:48:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1s PHP/8.1.12
Location: http://localhost/NEWNAME/item/a-long-file-name-separated-by-hyphens
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

curl -I 'localhost/OLDNAME/item/a-long-file-name-separated-by-hyphens-2'
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 03 Mar 2023 20:49:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1s PHP/8.1.12
Location: http://localhost/NEWNAME/item/a-long-file-name-separated-by-hyphens
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've tried the rule, but it seems to only change OLDNAME to NEWNAME. The '-2' remains.

Comment: Yes, you were correct. It was my browser cache. Your rule worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: If the URL doesn't contain the '-2' at the end, I still need it to change OLDNAME to NEWNAME. This only seems to work when the '-2' is present.

Comment: No luck. In the first scenario where the -2 string exists, the rule changes OLDNAME to NEWNAME but it doesn't remove the -2 from the URL. In the second scenario where the -2 string does not exist, the rule doesn't change OLDNAME to NEWNAME. I cleared browser cache and tried 3 different browsers.

Comment: Try my updated answer. I have tested on both cases and it works fine. btw your question should make it clear that `-2` is optional.

Comment: Yes, I could've been clearer. My apologies. I've updated the question so it's clearer for anyone reading it in the future. I've tried the new rule.  In the first scenario where the -2 string exists, the rule works perfectly. In the second scenario where the -2 string does not exist, the rule doesn't change OLDNAME to NEWNAME.

Comment: That's not correct. It is working for both the cases. You probably still have browser cache issue. I am posting debug output using `curl` command.

Comment: Your rule worked as expected. Thank you!