# htaccess rule doesn't work when index.php is present in the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following `.htaccess` rule changes `OLDNAME` to `NEWNAME` and removes the string `-2` from the end of the URL if it exists.

```
RewriteRule ^OLDNAME/(.+?)(?:-2)?/?$ /NEWNAME/$1 [L,NC,R=302,NE]
```

The rule was written by @anubhava in this post ([How to use htaccess to change a folder name and remove a string from the end of a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75629361/how-to-use-htaccess-to-change-a-folder-name-and-remove-a-string-from-the-end-of)). It works great on the following URLs.

- `https://example.com/OLDNAME/item/a-long-file-name-separated-by-hyphens-2`
- `https://example.com/OLDNAME/item/a-long-file-name-separated-by-hyphens`

While digging into this further, I found that if a URL includes `index.php`, it causes this rule to fail. The rule doesn't work on either of the following URLs.

- `https://example.com/index.php/OLDNAME/item/a-long-file-name-separated-by-hyphens-2`
- `https://example.com/index.php/OLDNAME/item/a-long-file-name-separated-by-hyphens`

I've tried modifying the rule to include `index.php`, but I don't have the syntax right yet.

RewriteRule ^index.php/OLDNAME/(.+?)(?:-2)?/?$ /NEWNAME/$1 [L,NC,R=302,NE]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The rule you posted is basically correct (except that you should backslash-escape the literal dot and make the `index.php/` part _optional_ in order to handle both URLs with and without the `index.php/` prefix). However, if it's not doing anything then it's likely conflicting with other rules. Please update your question with your complete `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Hello MrWhite. Thank you for the help. I added the content of my .htaccess file.

Comment: You need to edit/update your question, rather than post an "answer". However, I don't see this updated rule anywhere in your config?

Comment: MrWhite, thank you for the tips on posting and commenting here. I need to modify the rule I just posted as an answer to accommodate two different "OLDNAMES" - OLDNAME1 and OLDNAME2. I'm not sure about the etiquette here. Should I edit this question or open a new question?

Answer (score 0):

This rule is working for me. Now, index.php can be present in the URL or not.

```
RewriteRule ^(index\.php/)?OLDNAME/(.+?)(?:-2)?/?$ /NEWNAME/$2 [L,NC,R=302,NE]
```